# oracle how to find number of months between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out a number of moths between two dates.
Date 1:  20200401 (YYYYMMDD)
Date 2:  20200515 (YYYYMMDD)

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN( TO_DATE ('20200515', 'YYYYMMDD'), 
                       TO_DATE ('20200401', 'YYYYMMDD') )  month 
  FROM dual;
```

I got the result **1.451** . but I am expecting the result to be 1.5

Comment: Use `ROUND(..., 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MONTHS_BETWEEN.html#GUID-E4A1AEC0-F5A0-4703-9CC8-4087EB889952

Pay attention to the function specification. Unless the day-of-the-month is the same OR the two dates are both end-of-month dates, the computation is made **as if every month had 31 days**!!

So, in your case the result is 1 + 14/31 = 1.45161....

In any case, your example shows 1 month and 14 days; not clear why you expected 1.5 - even if you expected the computation to assume that every month has 30 days. (May has 31 days!) You are probably thinking of "dates" as individual entities, and consider both dates as INCLUDED in the interval. That is not how date arithmetic works; "15 May 2020" means midnight at the BEGINNING of the day, so the computation does NOT include the 24 hours of the last date, 15 May 2020.